# How can I add a onclick action on a specific column in a standard datatable component?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, datatable, js

How to have on click action for specific column in data table in lwc.
consder this as example, js:

```
columns = [ {label: 'Opportunity name', fieldName: 'opportunityName', type: 'text'},
{label: 'Confidence', fieldName: 'confidence', type: 'percent', cellAttributes: { iconName: { fieldName: 'trendIcon' }, iconPosition: 'right' }} ];
```

I want to open a modal by clicking on "Confidence".  if I give `onclick` in html, for example:

```
<lightning-datatable data={data} columns={columns}" onclick={openmodal}></lightning-datatable>
```

In this case modal will open wherever I click on data-table, instead of specific column.

Anyone knows any solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement a custom data type with your html executing modal on click

Recently a new feature was released which allows to define custom data types in standard `lightning:datatable` component.

Create a LWC component `customTable` with the following JS

```
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import clickModal from './clickModal.html';
 
export default class CustomTable extends LightningDatatable {
    static customTypes = {
        clickModal: {
            template: clickModal,
            standardCellLayout: true
        }
    }
}
```

Create in the `customTable` folder additional file `clickModal.html`

```
<template>
    <lightning-formatted-text value={value} onclick={openModal}></lightning-formatted-text>
</template>
```

Use overridden version of Lightning Data Table

```
<c-custom-table ...>
```

Set the column type to `clickModal`

```
columns = [ {
    label: 'Opportunity name', fieldName: 'opportunityName', type: 'text'}, {
    label: 'Confidence', fieldName: 'confidence', type: 'clickModal', cellAttributes: {
        iconName: { fieldName: 'trendIcon' },
        iconPosition: 'right'
    }
} ];
```

Comment: sorry, i didnt understand how will that become specific to a column. could you please elaborate if possible

Comment: I have updated my answer to include more details